# Updating rootview controller based on data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing, swift3

I have data in my parse server. and when my data is fetched I want to have the ability to change the root view controller of my app depending if my data changes in my server. Now it works the first time and chooses one root view controller but when i change the data in my server to test all scenarios, my root view controller isn't updating. Here is the code in my appdelagate. Can someone show me how i could fix this. Here is the code from my appdelgate. How can I change this so that the root view controller updates based on the changing data in my parse server.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    let storyboardOne = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let storyboardTwo = UIStoryboard(name: "Login:SIgnUp", bundle: nil)
    let HomePage = storyboardOne.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePage") as! HomePageViewController
    let RestrictedPage = storyboardOne.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StatusLockedOrSuspended") as! RestrictedViewController
    let SignUpPage = storyboardTwo.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInSecondSignup") as! LogInSignUpViewControllerViewController
    if let window = self.window{
        if PFUser.current() == nil{
            window.rootViewController = HomePage
        }else{
            if PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Restricted") as? String == "" || PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Restricted") as? String == nil {
                if PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "username") as? String == "" || PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "password") as? String == ""{
                    window.rootViewController = SignUpPage
                }else{
                    window.rootViewController = HomePage
                }
            }else{
                window.rootViewController = RestrictedPage
            }

            print("hello\(PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Restricted") as? String)")
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Is it supposed close app and reopen it to change root view?

Comment: yes thats whats supposed to happen. If the data changes and the app refreshes or reloads then the root view controller will be changed. Can you possible propose an update to help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try move your code into method:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Comment: Any other suggestions

Comment: Looks the PFUser is not working, do you always has the HomePage? Make breakpoint in each if cases, to check PFUser.current() value.